# How to make bottom navigation item aligned in top flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I achieve this, I need the bottom navigation item aligned in half with background color.

[image]

My code:

```dart
 BottomNavigationBar(
            
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:  Icon(Feather.home),
                  label:"A",
                ),
        
               
              ],
            ),
```